# Как эффективнее всего обрабатывать столкновения в 2D игре?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр

У меня есть сцена, которая представляет собой, по сути, список объектов, которые она содержит. Какой-нибудь объект (содержащийся в сцене) может запросить у сцены: дай мне список объектов, которые пересекаются со мной. Когда это сцена получает такую команду, она проходит этот список от начала и до конца, и возвращает список. Проблема в том, что это довольно не эффективно, так как сложность растет квадратически (если коллижены запрашиваются каждым объектом). Есть идея отсортировать список - но не понятно по какому критерию и как быть с теми объектами, которые меняют свое положение на экране во время игры.

Также то как определяются столкновения: на данный момент для определения столкновений я исполюзую прямоугольники, которые всегда ориентированы в пространстве одинаково (тобишь под одним углом). Для тайловой игры - вполне годится, но если мне нужно будет поворачивать эти прямоугольники (или другие виды полигонов)? Как можно реализовать столкновения для произвольных полигонов?

Comment: Можно воспользоваться библиотекой Box2d. В ней есть как поддержка aabb запросов, так и обработка столкновений произвольный фигур

Comment: Если игра разделена на тайлы то можно AABB

Comment: А так, @VTT прав, можно использовать Box2D

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но я спрашивал не о том, какие либы юзать, а как это самому сделать. Да и Box2d мне сразу не понравился - прям на этапе сборки. Что это вообще такое? Привязка к IDE и какой-то premake? На дворе 2018 неужели нельзя взять нормальную систему сборки, например cmake?